# MySQL query multiple AND

Tags: mysql, sql

Supposing I have a MySQL table (meta_table) as follows with the following data:

```
meta_id,post_id,meta_key,meta_value
5,10,my_key1,value1
10,11,my_key2,value2
15,12,my_key3,value3
35,11,my_key4,value4
```

How can I get the post_id if meta_value is value2 and value4 (the answer should be 11).
I have tried this:

```
SELECT post_id from meta_table where meta_value='value2' and meta_value='value4'
```

But it does not return 11 as the post_id. Any suggestions?

Comment: Both Mahmoud's and Petah's answers should work. Can you have two different rows with post_id=11 and meta_value=value2? If yes then you might have to modify the answers slightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a join:

```
SELECT a.post_id
FROM meta_table AS a
JOIN meta_table AS b ON a.post_id = b.post_id
WHERE a.meta_value = 'value2' AND b.meta_value = 'value4'
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96d2b/4/0

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT post_id
from meta_table 
where meta_value IN ('value2', 'value4')
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9b30/1)

Comment: Good answer, but is it better than a join?

Comment: You can use a `JOIN`, as per my answer. The reason to is because `HAVING` is a post filter condition, when using a `JOIN` + `WHERE` is pre-filtered and makes better use of indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `OR`

```
SELECT post_id from meta_table where meta_value='value2' OR meta_value='value4'
```

Or you can use `IN`

```
SELECT post_id from meta_table where meta_value IN ('value2', 'value4')
```

Comment: This will get the `post_id` that has `value2` or `value4`. But I think the OP is looking for the `post_id`s that had both `value2` and `value4`.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Maybe. By the way I like your answer (+1)

Answer (score 0):

It should be :

`SELECT post_id from meta_table where meta_value='value2' or meta_value='value4'`

Answer (score 0):

query is : -

```
SELECT post_id from meta_table
where meta_value='value2' or meta_value='value4'
GROUP BY post_id
```